# weird symbols getting printed when press alt and arrow key in Visual Studios

Tags: windows, visual-studio

My system is printing symbols like (♠ ◘ ☻) these when i try to move cursor using alt key, which is causing problems while programming. Please help.

I have checked keyboard layout and setting, language setting, sticky keys and searched google and found nothing.

I dont know, if this is off topic here or not. If it is please let me know where can i get help regarding this.

thanks

Comment: Is it happening in any other program, such as Notepad?

Comment: every where i type

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a way to fix this with just windows, but I found that you can get around this with Autohotkey.

see: https://superuser.com/questions/668394/how-to-turn-off-alt-numeric-keypad-ascii-symbol-insertion